# MIT App Inventor 2 - Why use speed?

Tags: app-inventor

In my simple school project, there is a character that moves using buttons. When deciding how I wanted to move a sprite I stumbled upon this dilemma, why use speed? They look pretty much identical to me so far.

Here is what I mean (the top `MoveTo block`  and the bottom one seem the same)
[image: Difference]

of course given i set the `character.speed` to 10 in screen init.

---

What would I benefit by replacing the simple integer value with character.speed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the use of a constant considered better programming style than the use of a literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351022/why-is-the-use-of-a-constant-considered-better-programming-style-than-the-use-of)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `heading` and the `speed` of an image sprite and the image sprite will move automatically into the direction defied by `heading`. Alternatively use the `MoveTo` method to set the image sprite to a defined x/y coordinate.

See also the [documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/animation.html#ImageSprite)

> **Heading**
>
> Returns the sprite's heading in degrees above the positive x-axis. Zero degrees is toward the right of the screen; 90 degrees is toward
>   the top of the screen.
>
> **Interval**
>
> The interval in milliseconds at which the sprite's position is updated. For example, if the interval is 50 and the speed is 10, then
>   the sprite will move 10 pixels every 50 milliseconds.
>
> **Speed**
>
> The speed at which the sprite moves. The sprite moves this many pixels every interval.